# How to pass array of object to prop of a Svelte Custom Element?

Tags: javascript, svelte, custom-element

I've got a very simple Custom Element built from Svelte:

```
<svelte:options tag="menu-horizontal" />

<script>

// props
export let items = []

</script>

<nav>
    <ul>
      {#each items as item}
        <li>
          <a href={item.link}>{item.label}</a>
        </li>
      {/each}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I would like to pass an array of object to the prop "items" to populate my menu built in my Custom Element:

I tried this in a PHP file but without success:

```
<?= js('site/snippets/components/MenuHorizontal/assets/js/bundle.js', ['type' => 'module']) ?>

<div id="test"></div>

<script>
    let data;
    data = [
        { label: "Home" , link: "https://localhost" },
        { label: "Blog" , link: "https://localhost/blog" },
        { label: "About" , link: "https://localhost/about" }
    ];
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = `<menu-horizontal></menu-horizontal>`;
    document.querySelector('menu-horizontal').items = data;
    
</script>
```

The menu stay empty, there is no error. This is what I get in my browser console:
[Browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4435v.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the execution order is wrong here and the component has not been loaded yet when you try to use it. Module scripts are deferred by default<sup>1</sup> and thus execute later than regular scripts by default, check the output of this for example:

```html
<script type="module">
  console.log('module run');
</script>
<script>
  console.log('regular script run');
</script>
```

You can try to switch the type of the script that uses the component to `module` as well, then it *should* execute in the correct order. You could also import the component directly from the inline module script and drop the separate `bundle.js`.

Another option would be using [`customElements.whenDefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/whenDefined) to wait for the registration to finish before inserting the element into the HTML.

<sub><sup>1</sup> There are [other differences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#other_differences_between_modules_and_standard_scripts) as well.</sub>

---

Concrete example with custom element being defined too late:

```html
<script type="module">
  class CustomElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super()
      this.shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });

      this.shadow.innerHTML = 'Initial Content';
    }

    set customProperty(value) {
      this.shadow.innerHTML = value;
    }
  }

  customElements.define('test-element', CustomElement);
</script>

<div id="target"></div>

<script>
  target.innerHTML = '<test-element></test-element>';
  const element = target.querySelector('test-element');
  element.customProperty = 'Changed Content';
  console.log('Element type:', element.constructor.name);
</script>
```

With change to `type="module"`:

```html
<script type="module">
  class CustomElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super()
      this.shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });

      this.shadow.innerHTML = 'Initial Content';
    }

    set customProperty(value) {
      this.shadow.innerHTML = value;
    }
  }

  customElements.define('test-element', CustomElement);
</script>

<div id="target"></div>

<script type="module">
  target.innerHTML = '<test-element></test-element>';
  const element = target.querySelector('test-element');
  element.customProperty = 'Changed Content';
  console.log('Element type:', element.constructor.name);
</script>
```

Using `whenDefined`:

```html
<script type="module">
  class CustomElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super()
      this.shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });

      this.shadow.innerHTML = 'Initial Content';
    }

    set customProperty(value) {
      this.shadow.innerHTML = value;
    }
  }

  customElements.define('test-element', CustomElement);
</script>

<div id="target"></div>

<script>
  customElements.whenDefined('test-element').then(() => {
    target.innerHTML = '<test-element></test-element>';
    const element = target.querySelector('test-element');
    element.customProperty = 'Changed Content';
    console.log('Element type:', element.constructor.name);
   });
</script>
```